# How do I find the location of a particular string in a string array?

Tags: c#

Yes, this is for school work however the question is a very small part of work and I feel as though it's almost negligible.

In short, I have used a string array to print a grid like this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (row = 0; row <= 5; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column <= 5; column++)
    {
        RandomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 13);
        if (RandomNumber == 3)
            luckDipBoard[row, column] = "You Win ";
        else
            luckDipBoard[row, column] = "You Lose ";
    }
}

//Display board
for (row = 0; row <= 5; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column <= 5; column++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(column * 10, row * 2);

        if (luckDipBoard[row, column] == "You Win ")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

        Console.Write(luckDipBoard[row, column]);
    }
}
```

It prints the array grid and colours the variables accordingly. However, what I want to be able to do is for the user to be able to input a location, which I have written:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a row");
rowChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Input a column");
columnChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Clear();
```

However, I have no idea how to turn these variables into a location in the array and search the array with these co-ordinates and find out what is inside of the location. So for example if the grid printed randomly and column 2 row 1 was "You Win ", and the user inputted column 2 row 1, it would simply add credits to a variable.

If somebody could point me in the right direction of:

- Using the two input values as a location
- Searching the array and returning the value inside of the location

  int TextIndex = Array.FindIndex(luckDipBoard, m => m == "You Win ");

Errors: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Array.FindIndex(T[], Predicate)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Yes, only to return errors which I don't understand.

Comment: Which are those errors? Post in your question please.

Comment: If you are entering a row and column number, you can access the position in the array by using luckDipBoard[row, column] as you have done in your existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `Array.FindIndex` doesn't work is that it only works with *vectors* (i.e `string[]`) - but you have a 2D array (i.e. `string[,]`). AFAIK, none of the regular array hunting methods work on multi-dimensional arrays, so you have two options:

- do the hunt yourself by looping over the x/y dimensions manually
- linearize your array and deal with the *dimensionality* manully (this would mean having a `string[]` instead, and computing the offsets via multiplication)

If you're fairly unfamiliar with it, the first approach (looping over x/y) is probably easier than the second (which would involve changing just about every line of code).

Comment: How would I loop over the x/y dimensions?

Comment: @JoePodmore pretty much like you already are in `//Display board`

Comment: Thought so, how would I go about using the user's input though? I only want one value in the array to be chosen, as I feel if I looped through all of them then it would give me lots of values if there was more than one "You Win"

Comment: @JoePodmore it is a little unclear what you're *trying* to do, to be honest - do you just need to check `if(luckDipBoard[rowChoice, columnChoice] == "You Win ")` ?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did previously however I used = instead of ==. Much appreciated.